# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: query of: abc.def.mypackage.orm.Employee

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I am getting the following error when I am trying to execute the `insertEmployeeDetails` method  :

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: query of: abc.def.mypackage.orm.Employee [INSERT INTO Employee (name,definition,( SELECT value_emp_id FROM COMPANY_DATA WHERE testing_id = 1234 AND company_employee_id = 3345))]

Looking at similar online other posts on Stack overflow, say for example, the following one says:

[org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480018/org-hibernate-queryexception-could-not-resolve-property)

that "***we don't make reference to database column names, we reference property names instead***".So I have clearly mentioned `name` and `definition` as defined in the entity class `Employee` below. The subquery where I am trying to get the value of column `COLUMN_ID` uses the sub query so I am not sure if I would be able to use something in agreement with HQL rules?, I mean that `SELECT` subquery which is supposed to pull `value_emp_id` from `COMPANY_DATA` table is a SQL query that I have mentioned. Does that needs to be modified? Could this be the reason for this type of error? Please advise.

My Entity Class `Employee.java` is as follows:

```
package abc.def.mypackage.orm

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
 public int getEmployeeId() {
  return employeeId;
 }

 public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
  this.employeeId = employeeId;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public int getIsCorrect() {
  return isCorrect;
 }

 public void setIsCorrect(int isCorrect) {
  this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
 }

 public int getIsWrong() {
  return isWrong;
 }

 public void setIsWrong(int isWrong) {
  this.isWrong = isWrong;
 }

 public int getCompanyId() {
  return companyId;
 }

 public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
  this.companyId = companyId;
 }

 public Integer getTransactionId() {
  return transactionId;
 }

 public void setTransactionId(Integer transactionId) {
 this.transactionId = transactionId;
 }

 public String getDefinition() {
  return definition;
 }

 public void setDefinition(String definition) {
  this.definition = definition;
 }

 @Id
 @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seqgen")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqgen", sequenceName = "EMPLOYEE_AUTOINC_SEQ")
 private int employeeId;

 @Column(name = "NAME")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "DEFINITION")
 private String definition;

 @Column(name = "IS_CORRECT")
 private int isCorrect;

 @Column(name = "IS_WRONG")
 private int isWrong;

 @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
 private int companyId;

 @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_ID", nullable = true)
 private Integer transactionId;


}
```

Here is how I am using the HQL in my method :

```
public boolean insertEmployeeDetails(Employee employee)
    {
        logger.debug("Starting EmployeeDaoImpl.insert()  .....");
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        boolean status = true;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Employee (name,definition,"
                    + "( SELECT value_emp_id FROM COMPANY_DATA WHERE testing_id = 1234 AND"
                    + " company_employee_id = 3345))";

            int createdEntities = session.createQuery( hqlInsert )
                    .executeUpdate();

            session.persist(employee);
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("Checking for hqlInsert");
            System.out.println(hqlInsert);

            System.out.println("Checking for CreatedEntities");
            System.out.println(createdEntities);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            status = false;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        logger.debug("Completed EmployeeDaoImpl.insert()  .....");
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I am having some other issues with my SQL query after using your approach for which I am creating a new post.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, I will be glad to help you with this new issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are confusing **[`createQuery()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery(java.lang.String))** with **[`createSQLQuery()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery(java.lang.String))**, because `createQuery()` executes  a `HQL` query and not an `SQL` query as you can see in the documentation:

> **createQuery**
>
> Create a new instance of Query ***for the given HQL query string***.

In fact the `hqlInsert` query `string` you passed to the `createQuery()` method is an `SQL` insert query, which is unsopported by `createQuery()`, you need to use `createSQLQuery()` so you can execute it with `Hibernate`, and make sure to use database columns instead of Entity attributes on it as it's an SQL query.